# Outlook client unable to connect exchange server

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Outlook Client is not updating.

[image]

So, I tried to enable Encryption option as I found many blog stating to enable this option.

[image]

But, this option is greyed out, which means I can't do anything. So, any clue, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Work Offline" is active. If that's not the case,

Click on File > Account Settings > Account Settings... > select your Exchange account > Repair

Maybe your Exchange Server has been changed without notification, it happens sometimes. repair will find the good server.

Comment: where is this option `Work Offline`

Comment: It should be in the Send & Receive tab. If it is not there, it has been customized by the IT department. Clicking on Send/Receive All Folders instead should reconnect to the server.